# why does R print a print assignment?

Tags: r, assign

I am wondering why R is printing the following assignment (as if it was called):

```
command1 <- print("hello") # output: [1] "hello"
```

whereas R does neither print assignment of objects

```
command2 <- c(1,2,3) # no output
```

nor assignment of other functions

```
command3 <- summary(cars) # no output
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the assignment, it's the call to `print()` that produces the output. Printing to the screen is what `print()` is designed to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but print() is a function like summary(). So why is print() called and summary() not?

Comment: @Richard: They are both called. One prints to the screen, and the other one doesn't.

Comment: Perhaps I used 'call' wrongly? Clearly, in `command3 <- summary(cars)`, there is no execution of the function summary(). So why is there an execution of the print() function in `command1 <- print("hello")`

Comment: @Richard do you think that a function is executed only if something is printed? Clearly, the `summary` function is executed.

Comment: @nicola thanks for your response. I indeed think that in `command3 <- summary(cars)` no function is executed, but that the function summary() with object 'cars' is assigned to command3. I think that the summary is only executed when I type command3 <enter>. I am perhaps mistaken in this assumption?

Comment: You're wrong. A function is executed when called and the return value is assigned to a symbol (`command3` in your example). The goal of a function is (usually) to evaluate a return value. Some functions may have side-effects, which can be writing to a file or to print something on screen. The `print` function is one of them. When the evaluation of a function is not assigned to a symbol, the R interpreter implicitly calls the `print` function on the return value. That's why you see the result on the screen.

Comment: @Richard IMHO you are thinking of something in the lines of `command3 <- summary; command3(cars) `